# Display computer information in RDC

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

What is the setting or configuration change in Remote Desktop Connection to display the server information (Server name, IP addresses) when connected to a windows server 2003 server?

Comment: Are you looking for a pop-up window, or some obvious way of displaying who you're logging on to?

Comment: It displays the server information the same way as BGInfo

Answer (score 10):

You might be thinking of [BGinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx)?

EDIT to add:
If you put this line in a logon script for the system (or the user profile, GPO, whatever your preferred way), you'll get the BGinfo information "tattoo" on your desktop without actually installing BGinfo to the system:

```
\\server\share\bginfo.exe /I\\server\share\bginfo-std.bgi /accepteula /timer:0
```

This assumes you've previously run BGinfo to create the bginfo.bgi config file, and placed it and the bginfo executable at \\server\share

Comment: I do mot think that was it because I remember a fellow programmer able to do this without installing additional software.

Comment: +1 - I have been wondering about this for several years.  THANKS!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more? What's the bgi file for?

Comment: The BGI file describes what information bginfo displays on the wallpaper.

Comment: bofe: When you first run BGinfo, it presents you with a screen that looks like this ( http://tinyurl.com/lxr69l ) - allowing you to choose what information about the computer will be presented on the desktop. This config info is then saved as a *.bgi file.

Answer (score 1):

\\live.sysinternals.com\Tools\Bginfo.exe is on the internet (via smb or CIFS)... your going to take a performance hit if you use it but at least you do not have install on the local network.